# How to dispatch slice reducer from a library not a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm currently building a React application based on https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template.

This boilerplate, uses Redux with slices. Which works fine, as long as I want to update the state from within a React component. However, I am struggling with updating my application state from somewhere else. In my particular case I want to dispatch a logout event as soon as I get a response that I am unauthorized, basically resetting the application state.

Now this obviously can happen in any API request and therefor I don't want this to handle within the React component and rather handle it in my API library that handles API requests.

From what I've read so far, I should be able to dispatch an event by simply accessing the store. In this boilerplate the store is defined in the `src/index.tsx` file. So after adding the `export` keyword to it I thought I would be able to do this:

```
import { store } from 'index';
import { appActions } from 'app/slice';

console.log(store.getState());
store.dispatch(appAction.logout());
```

Somehow the state here is always undefined, even tho there is a state when I access it via a React component. Also the reducer called above never picks up the dispatched event. I also tried to encapsulate it with a timeount, in case this is just because the store isn't initialized yet, but that's not the case.

I'd appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is how I finally made it work:

I imported the React hook of my slice into the `src/app/index.tsx` file

```
import { useAppSlice } from 'app/slice';

export function App() {

  // use the React hook
  useAppSlice();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        ...
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Even tho I'm not using the slice in this particular controller, it somehow "connects" with the store, so that I can use the slice from within any sub-controller or any library.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check the path is correct to get to the store.

After that please try again. I think your method is right.

If it is not working, please try to use the require method

```
require('index');
require('app/slice');
​
console.log(store.getState());
store.dispatch(appAction.logout());
​
```

Comment: The path was correct. See my answer below. Thanks!